# Is it possible to compile decompiled hex code?

Tags: c#, compilation, hex, recompile

Is it possible to compile a `SoapHexBinary` back to an .exe

```cs
var str = new SoapHexBinary(File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\test\test.exe")).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: You might want to actually read the mouse-over info on the "compile" tag; "Compilation is the transformation of source text into some other form or representation." There is no source code involved in this. Text-format bytes do not equal source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
byte[] bytes = SoapHexBinary.Parse(str).Value
```

Note that there's no "compile" here - it is just bytes that *happen to be an exe*; once you get the bytes back, they are still the same exe (if you'd sent a gif file, it would still be the same gif file, etc). If you want it as a file: write the bytes to the file system.